# Converting T-Bill weekly data to a Monthly level data

Tags: python, dataframe, finance

I want to convert my weekly T bill data to a monthly level

Here is a sample of my Data:

```
0   1986-Jan    7.04
1   1986-01-10  7.13
2   1986-01-17  7.17
3   1986-01-24  6.99
4   1986-01-31  6.98
```

I want to get the average of the data at a month level.

For the above example, the out should be:

```
0   1986 Jan  7.062
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
three_month_t_bill_df['Month_Number'] = three_month_t_bill_df['observation_date'].dt.month
three_month_t_bill_df['Year'] = three_month_t_bill_df['observation_date'].dt.year

df2 = three_month_t_bill_df.groupby(['Year','Month_Number']).agg("mean")
```

I am getting the following output:

```
1986    1   7.0620
        2   7.0650
        3   6.5650
        4   6.0625
...
1987    1   5.4640
        2   5.5925
        3   5.5875
```

Can someone help in getting the year in all rows and month name instead of month number?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @DMalan Sorry I forgot to upload the code.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your date column is called `Date` and your dataframe is `df` and your values is called `Value`, so you could do:

```
# Creating a new column to store the new format
df["DateMonth"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime('%Y %b')
# Group by Value column and get the average
df.groupby(['DateMonth'])['Value'].mean()
```

With that, my output is:

```
DateMonth
1986 Jan    7.062
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

You could also check [Python strftime cheatsheet](https://strftime.org/) to check new formats if you want.

Comment: I tried this but the date comes out not as column name. I want Date to be a column name.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1.

You can use `import calendar` / `df = df['Month_number'].apply( lambda k: calendar.month_name[k])` to get the month names.

Part 2.

The data is all in there, but `groupby` returns a special `DataFrameGroupBy` object that doesn't display the grouped data.  You can convert that to a normal data frame using `df2 = df2.to_frame()`.